# Linq2Entities CompiledQuery for query that uses joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a query that is not performing too well, e.g. the generated SQL code is sub-optimal.

The original statement looked something like this (simplified):

```
ctx.Table1.Where(t => ...)
          .OrderBy(t => ....)
          .Select(t => new {Table1 = t,
                            SomeProperty = t.Table2.SomeProperty,
                            SomeProperty2 = t.Table2.SomeProperty2,
                            AnotherProperty = t.Table3.AnotherProperty,
                            ...
                            }
```

I looked in SQL Profiler and found that the generated SQL would join the same table multiple times and the statement would take around 1 second to execute.

I then rewrote the statement to something along these lines:

```
from t in ctx.Table1
join t2 in ctx.Table2 on t.key equals t2.key into lt2
from t2 in lt2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t3 in ctx.Table3 on t.key equals t3.key into lt3
from t3 in lt3.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t ...
orderby t...
select new {Table1 = t, .... }
```

This generated a much nicer statement, that when grabbed from SQL profiler and executed in Management studio is double as fast as the statement generated by the code in the previous example.

However when running the code from the second example, the time taken for EF to generate the expression far superseeds the time gained from the query optimization.

So how do I go about writing statement number two as a `CompiledQuery`. I basically don't know how to return an anonymous type from a `CompiledQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found for using CompiledQueries is:

1. Add a private InitQueryX() method before each QueryX() method that uses LINQ to Entity.
2. Use attributes and reflection call all the InitQueryX() methods from an Init() method.
3. Call Init() method once on app start.

This forces compilation of queries at start, yet enables writing queries in a more flexible manner then CompiledQueries do.

The InitQueryX() should use multiple dummy inputs so that it covers all the paths within QueryX() method (sort of like unit tests code coverage).

When possible, the InitQueryX()'s inputs should be mocks that result in 0 rows in database, so that the Init() method will take less time to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class if your return object will have 8 or less properties. If you have more properties and don't want to declare a class for those properties you can use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) as the return type.